# d3 find equally spaced points on a line with alignment

Tags: d3.js

I have three parameters alignment , no of points and distance;

I have drawn a line fro p1 to p2.

P2 is draggable.
when I select alignment = 'justify' interpolate between p1 and p2 gives  the x and y coordinate points on a line with equal spaced.

I need help to computing other alignments left, right and center;

```js
    const p1 = {x: 40, y: 40};
    let p2 = {x: 160, y: 160};
    const cp1 ={x: 0, y: 0};
    const cp2 ={x: 0, y: 0};        
    var w = 600, h = 500;
    var svgCanvas = d3.select('#seating_chart').append('svg').attr("width", w).attr("height", h);
    var gContainer = svgCanvas.append('g').classed("outline", true);
    var dragBehavior = d3.drag().on("drag", alterLine);
    //const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    init();
function calculatePoint(a,b,distance)
{

    // a. calculate the vector from o to g:
    let vectorX = b.x - a.x;
    let vectorY = b.y - a.y;
    // b. calculate the proportion of hypotenuse
    let factor = distance / Math.sqrt(vectorX * vectorX + vectorY * vectorY);

    // c. factor the lengths
    vectorX *= factor;
    vectorY *= factor;

    // d. calculate and Draw the new vector,
    // return new Point((int)(a.X + vectorX), (int)(a.Y + vectorY));
    return {x:a.x + vectorX,y:a.y + vectorY}
}
    function alterLine(e){
        selectedP = d3.select(this);
        var parentNode = d3.select(this.parentNode);
        var line = d3.select(this.parentNode).select('line');
        var pointCX = e.x;
        var pointCY = e.y;

        //rendering selected circle on drag
        selectedP.attr("cx", pointCX).attr("cy", pointCY);
        line.attr('x2',pointCX);
        line.attr('y2',pointCY);
        p2.x = pointCX;
        p2.y = pointCY;
    }
    
    
    no_points.addEventListener("input", update);
    dist.addEventListener("input", update);
    function init(){
        gContainer.append('circle')
                        .attr("cx", p1.x)
                        .attr("cy", p1.y)
                        .attr("r",  4);
        gContainer.append('circle').classed('drag',true)
                        .attr("cx", p2.x)
                        .attr("cy", p2.y)
                        .attr("r",  4)
                        .call(dragBehavior);
        gContainer.append("line")          // attach a line
                .attr("x1", p1.x)     // x position of the first end of the line
                .attr("y1", p1.y)      // y position of the first end of the line
                .attr("x2", p2.x)     // x position of the second end of the line
                .attr("y2", p2.y); 
        d3.select('#no_of_points_text').text(no_points.value);
        d3.select('#distance_text').text(dist.value);

    }
    function update() {
        const a = alignment.value
        const n = no_points.value;
        const d = dist.value;
    
    if(Number(a)==2){
        di = n*d*2;
        var p3 = calculatePoint(p1,p2,di);
        lineInter = d3.interpolate(p1,p3);
    } else if(Number(a)==3){
        di = n*d*2;
        var p3 = calculatePoint(p2,p1,di);
        lineInter = d3.interpolate(p2,p3);
    } else {
        lineInter = d3.interpolate(p1,p2);
    }            c= 1/n;
        d3.select('#no_of_points_text').text(n);
        d3.select('#distance_text').text(d);
        gContainer.selectAll('.point').remove();
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
            pc = lineInter(c);
            gContainer.append('circle').classed('point',true)
                        .attr("cx", pc.x)
                        .attr("cy", pc.y)
                        .attr("r",  d);
            c+= 1/n
        }
       
    }
```

```css
 svg {
            border: solid 1px rgba(221, 61, 16, 0.71);
        }
        circle {
            fill: lightgreen;
            stroke: green;
            /* stroke-width: 2px; */
            fill-opacity: 0.5;
        }
        line {
            stroke: #563aff;
            stroke-width: 2px;
        }
        .drag {
            cursor: move;
        }
```

```html
Alingment    <select id="alignment">
                    <option value="1" selected>Justify</option>
                    <option value="2">Left</option>
                    <option value="3">Right</option>
                    <option value="4">Center</option>
    </select>
    No of Points: <input id="no_points" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="1"/>
   Distance: <input id="dist" type="range" min="4" max="50" step="1" value="4"/>
   <div id="info"> 
    No of points<span id="no_of_points_text"></span>
    Distance<span id="distance_text"></span>
   </div>
   <!-- <canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200" ></canvas> -->
   <div id="seating_chart"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var interpolatorFactory = function(a, b) {
    return function(t) {
        // Your custom scale function here, 
        // where you interpolate between a and b 
        // using the parameter t.
        return a * (1 - t) + b * t;
    };
};
```

Above linerInterpolate works when the alignment is justify.

I have done with right and left only center I need help

Comment: The meaning of `alignment` is not so clear. Can you post a picture illustrating different alignments for the same parameters of points and distance?